# show content of iframe tab/app when post link

Tags: facebook, tabs, posting

I'f made a Facebook tab/app and published it on my facebook-page.
Now if I post the link to the tab/app (e.g. https://www.facebook.com/MY-FACEBBOK-NAME?sk=APP-ID)
it loads only my profile-image.

Is it possible to display the information from the meta property tags in the posting?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  However it's going to take some trickery to do it.

First, you will share the URL to a page on your website (off of facebook), that has the correct og meta tags defined.

Secondly, in that page where the og meta tags are defined, you will need to do a javascript redirect to the Facebook Page tab url.

Here's the secret magic that makes it work. Facebook's linter that reads the og meta tags will not run the javascript and hence will pick up the correct values.  Yet a user who clicks the link will get redirected to the page tab.

Comment: Thank you! I also thought about this already.

But my problem is, that the user did not know this "off facebook" url and will still post the tab url to share it.
I would like to get the Information right out of the tab url, if possible.

But this is a nice workaround, if only I will post the URL.

Comment: You will need to be sure to only give out the off-facebook url to be shared.  Otherwise you cannot spec out the og tags of a page tap app.